# How can i redirect my subdomain with www to main domain?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have change my blog website form http://www.blog.pixel2pixeldesign.com/ to https://pixel2pixeldesign.com

Now all old post do not get redirect to my new domain because it consider www.blog as my new subdomain.

Can you please help me with the .htaccess code to redirect
http://www.blog.pixel2pixeldesign.com/creative-unique-business-cards/
to
https://pixel2pixeldesign.com/creative-unique-business-cards/

This is my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pixel2pixeldesign\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.pixel2pixeldesign\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^p2ptuts\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.p2ptuts\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^psd\.p2ptuts\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.psd\.p2ptuts\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vector\.p2ptuts\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.vector\.p2ptuts\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a .htaccess file you can do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you have acces to the apach config a new virtualhost with a redirect directive, like

```
Redirect permanent / http://pixel2pixeldesign.com/
```

Would be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

The following code makes a 301 redirect to www version of your website

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```